# SWRevealViewController - front view under rear view

Tags: xcode, menu, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using the library SWRevealViewController for front and rear view, and it works.
The problem is that, when I click on menu button, the rear view si under the navigationbar, and fron view is shift to right.

Is possible to lock the front view and see the menu on top of navigation bar?

My code:

in Appdelegate:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    SplashScreenViewController *splashScreenViewController = (SplashScreenViewController *)[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splash"];
    UINavigationController *navControllerFront = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:splashScreenViewController];

    MenuNavigationViewController *menuViewController = (MenuNavigationViewController *)[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menu"];
    UINavigationController *navControllerRear = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];


    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:navControllerRear frontViewController:navControllerFront];

    revealController.delegate = self;
    self.viewController = revealController;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

FrontView file (is not splashscreen):

```
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
   [revealController panGestureRecognizer];
    [revealController tapGestureRecognizer];

    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    [navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *revealButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    revealButtonItem.image = [revealButtonItem.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButtonItem;
```

How to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot

[image]

*Edit*: I've resolved with this code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)revealViewController.frontViewController;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NewSplashScreenViewController *start = (NewSplashScreenViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splashnew"];
    [navController setViewControllers: @[start] animated: YES];

    [revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
    [revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

Comment: I've added my code that resolve the problem (for me)

Comment: Hi, do you solve this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive answer to this question, but I needed to implement the same functionality in my project.

The author of SWRevealController has insisted on a way to implement this functionality. Am still working on it.

The link is : https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/312

I guess people are still not able to figure out how exactly to do it.